# trying to compare local storage string to url string not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Here's the basic premise of what I'm trying to do:

Let's say you have a simple nested list:

```
<ul>
   <li>chevy</li>
   <li>dodge</li>
   <li id="trucks">ford
      <ul>
        <li>ranger</li>
        <li>f150</li>
        <li>f250</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>kia</li>
</ul>
```

By default the nested ford menu options are hidden. Once you click on the "ford" link, when the new page opens, the nested div with "ranger", "f150", and "f250" would open and show the nested menu.

My idea was to grab the id on the `<li>` on the click event, put it in `localStorage` as a string, then on the new page load, compare the url substring to the local storage string and if they match, put a class of `display: block` which would then make the menu visible.

Here is the jQuery I have so far, but when I try to compare the two, I keep getting the "no" saying these are not the same. This is the one thing which I'm hung up on right now and can't seem to figure out.

```
//get the id on the div and then store as a string
function storeId() {
    $mtv('.features > ul > li > a').click(function() {
        var name = $mtv (this).attr('id');
        localStorage.setItem( 'name', JSON.stringify(name) );
    });

};

//retrieve the storage item and compare to id clicked
function retrieveId() {
    localStorage.getItem( 'name' );
    var retrieve = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var currentUrl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1).replace('.html', '');
    if (currentUrl === retrieve ){
        alert("yes");
    }
    else {
        alert("no")
    }
};
```

any help is greatly appreciated,

D

Comment: What is `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: I would suggest using a javascript debugger to inspect values, you'll find this very useful with JavaScript problems in general. firebug or chrome's dev-tools are both great and there's lots of info available on using them.

Comment: @Blender - (window.location.pathname) gives you the current URL of the page you're on. There's a ton of different ways of getting the URL, I just chose that one.

Comment: @Dade: I mean, what does it output for you.

Comment: @Blender - I feel like you're a teacher trying to get me to understand something without actually telling me - right? I think you want me say it outputs an object and my problem is I'm trying to compare an object to a string - correct? Thus, in order to make a comparison, I need to covert my object to a string before I compare it to the localStorage string. . .

Answer (score 0):

with `var name = $mtv(this).attr('id');` you are trying to get id of link

*as you want to get id of the li* Try this -

```
var name = $mtv(this).closest('li').attr('id');
```